# How many Pokemiles can Pokebank store before redeeming them?

Tags: pokemon-bank

I forgot to check my Pokebank for months, is there a limit to Pokemiles I can store before redeeming and sending them to a game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**.

The maximum value of Pokemiles you can have at once on Pokebank without redeeming them is 65535.
This odd number is due to a 16-bit integer value used to store that number.

This means it's better to redeem them once in a while. However, Battle Points counter is capped too, and it can't exceed 9999 BPs.